# Mean and autocorrelation of a random process which pmf is a constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question:

Denote a discrete random process $X[n]$ be generated by repeated tosses of a fair die. Let the values of the random process be equal to the result of each toss

Thinking:

Now i know the pmf of $X[n]$ is $\frac{1}{6}$ for $x=1$~$6$,and $E[X]$ should be $(1+2+3+4+5+6)\frac{1}{6}$,but i don't know how to calculate the autocorrelation according the definition,that is,$E[X(t+\tau)X(t)]$,the $X(t+\tau)$ should be the same as X(t),so is the autocorrelation become $E[\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}]$?it looks strange.

Comment: i don't understand your meaning,can you explain it with more detail?

Comment: Are you sure the definition of your autocorrelation is correct?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth sry,i miss something,i had modified it,thanks

Comment: I feel you are mixing your definitions of signals and probability. Maybe.

Comment: can you say how to solve this question?

Comment: I mean from intuition, there should be no relationship between rolls right?

Comment: yes,they should be independent